# apache application in local computer needs to be run anywhere over internet

Tags: networking, router, apache-http-server, port-forwarding

I'm running a apache server application in my local computer,All of computers connected to my router is able to access but a computer outside from router not able to access my application.I also configured port forwarding like as ipaddress:192.168.0.100 and external & internal port:80.
i have tried like "http://globelIpAddress:80/projectDirectory" but not works,so
please tell me how to access my application from anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You need to open 80 port in your router NAT to the computer that is hosting the app.